# Silverlight 4 buggy at least on Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have downloaded this twitter source code
http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silvester-A-Silverlight-Twitter-Widget.aspx

After opening in VS 2010 and setting the web project as startup I run it in IE 9 but then IE 9 asks me to install silverlight I said OK at the end it says it cannot install because it's already installed so in the end I cannot run the app.

Is this clearly a bug ? Is it possible to fix this as this app was developer maybe in older version of silverlight ?

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading the very latest (Feb 2011) developer runtime for Silverlight 4 which is found [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188039).

Answer (score 1):

http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Browser/ActiveXFiltering/About.html